# How can we find the possible values of 'a' in a system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

What is/are the possible value(s) of $a$ such that the system of linear equations in $x$,$y$, and $z$ has a unique solution?
$$\begin{align}
x-2y+az&=0\\
y+3z&=-1\\
-2x+3y+z&=-2
\end{align}$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write the system as $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 & a \\ 0 & 1 & 3 \\ -2 & 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Now think about what the determinant can tell you about the matrix/the corresponding linear mapping.